# Access html5 storages from native android code

Tags: java, android, html, cordova

I have developed phonegap application in android, now there is a requirement to update and access localstorage data from native code/android service in application. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can trigger a javascript function from your native code (via the webview object) and then access the localstorage.

Hope this helps! If you need something more specific, please shoot it!

Comment: its actually from a service, not sure how to manage with webview? should a new webview created then hidden and js function called to access storage?